# Default to Review Queues not Review Edits when Review button is clicked in new UI

Tags: discussion, top-bar

When I click the Review Queue button with the new top-nav, I am taken to Review Edits by default, which I don't have access to. Would it make more sense to default the navigation to the more accessible Review Queue types, at least until a user has access to other types?

[image: Screenshot of current default navigation.]